# Store matrices of different column size into one element

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have several matrices, with the same number of rows but different column size. I want to store them in one element (whatever that is), so I can access each matrix in a loop at different iterations.

Answer (score 2):

The only basic MATLAB class that can store different types in each of the elements is a [`cell array`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

```
A{1}='hello';
A{2}=rand(4,5);
A{3}=rand(4,25);
```

A cell array is accessed with curly brackets `{}`.

Read more in [the official documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html)

Comment: Was about to upvote your comment. But you deleted... so no one could copy ;)

Comment: @TonyTannous Noo, I delete it when I decide to answer. No advantage of having a comment and an answer saying the same

Comment: I was obviously joking... no offense.

Comment: @TonyTannous ;) none taken!